# SQL model/schema design, check constraints, FK or table redesign?

Tags: sql, database-design, entity-relationship, database-schema

I have the following models (simplified leaving all other fields out, focusing on primary key ID's):

```
[invoice]
 invoice_id
 customer_id
 invoice_description

[customer]
  customer_id
  company_id
  customer_name

[company]
 company_id
 company_name

[strategy]
 strategy_id
 strategy_descripton
```

A company contains many customers, which in turn can have many invoices belonging to that customer.

Although not shown above, I also wish to have a list of strategies, that belong to a company (and only one company).

I would like the customer, invoice, and company, to be able to define a 'default strategy' which references a strategy of the company to which they belong.

I know i could put an extra FK field called strategy_id in each table (invoice, customer and company), but how can i ensure that if changes are made (someone tries to move a strategy to a different company) we do not end up with an invoice, or customer pointing to a strategy that belongs in another company's strategy list?

How would i deal with this - Do i need to check all this in business logic, or use check constraints, or can this be achieved through table redesign and foreign keys?

Many thanks in advance,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mind if customer or invoice that belong to a company change their strategy if the company changes their strategy.

For example: If company1 has strategy1. It has customer1, customer2 (having invoice1). Then if company1 changes it's invoice to strategy2 is it ok if customer1, customer2 and invoice1 belong to strategy2 or strategy1.

If it doesn't matter do:

- Add constraint to the company table. To check the strategy of the customer/invoice find the parent company and check it's strategy.

Otherwise if it does matter:

1. Add constraint to the company table and don't allow it to be changed if there belongs child customer/invoice to the company (check if they exist).
2. Set a constraint to each table like you mentioned above.

If you want a more specific answer you will have to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Yes it would be important that if someone tried to change the strategy to a different company whilst it was in use, that this be disallowed.

If you have any links for SQL constraints conditions/code on achieving the above that would be great, normally i have done this checking only at the business logic level but more recently have grown concerned about protecting the application from strange states that are 'valid' in the database but invalid in my entity model.

You have answered my question with the above, thanks.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. If you have any more questions. :)

Comment: One final clarification/question, is it correct to also check these constraints in the business logic layer also (I am using EntityFramework with SQL backend), or just leave it for the database to handle? I want to avoid replication of work and implementation of rules at lots of different places.

Comment: I have been checking the constraints in my stored procedures. The only issue with this is you may duplicate it through several procedures. I think it is depends on how many people are working on the project and your own personal choice.

Comment: ok great Kyra, since i am using EntityFramework the actual underlying database is not defined, and since EF doesnt support check constraints, the logical place for these checks to take place are at the Business Logic layers. Thanks for the help, you really helped. Answered fully.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want every company to have many strategies, every strategy belonging to one company (so a `1:n` relationship between company and strategy). And also one default strategy for every company which is is also the default strategy for all its customers and their invoices.

You could define these constraints as foreign keys constraints by adding one more table `[company_default_strategy]` which is in a `1:1` relationship with the `[strategy]` table (some strategies are default):

```
[invoice]
 invoice_id     PK
 customer_id    FK  to  customer(customer_id)
 invoice_description

[customer]
 customer_id    PK
 company_id     FK  to  company(company_id)
 customer_name

[company]
 company_id     PK
 company_name

[strategy]
 strategy_id    PK
 company_id     FK  to  company(company_id)
 strategy_descripton

[company_default_strategy]
 company_id     PK, FK1 
 strategy_id    FK1
   FK1 (strategy_id, company_id)  to  strategy(strategy_id, company_id)
```